# Help with toString() - adding to collections

Tags: java

I am adding information from main()
I am adding different information for CD, DVD, book..

I have 3 separate classes - item has 3 classes in it...

1. project - main()
2. Library - this function does all the adding
3. Item(cd,dvd,book) inheritance

For Music i am adding band info, title info, keywords, and members..
I am adding members separately than of the other info..

As you can see the members is not outputing correctly as the others..

```
>>> music CDs:

-Music-
band: Jerry Garcia Band
# songs: 15
members: [Ljava.lang.String;@61de33
title: Don't Let Go

C:\Java\a03>
```

I am using the same toString() function for members as i am the rest, so i am not sure why it would do this..

I will give you as much info as i think you need to see..

Main() - as you can see it calls 2 different functions.

the addbandmembers is where i am having problems...

```
out.println(">>> adding items to library:\n");
item = library.addMusicCD("Europe In '72", "Grateful Dead", 12, "acid rock", "sixties", "jam bands");
    if (item != null) {
        library.addBandMembers(item, "Jerry Garcia", "Bill Kreutzman", "Keith Godcheaux");
        library.printItem(out, item);
        }
```

in Library class - here is the addbandmember function ..

Could this be the cause??

```
public void addBandMembers(Item musicCD, String... members)
{

    ((CD)musicCD).addband(members);

}
```

In the Items class here is the function addband - tostring()

here is the CD class which extends the items class..

```
class Item
{
    private String title;

    public String toString()
    {
        String line1 = "title: " + title + "\n";
        return line1;
    }

    public void print()
    {
        System.out.println(toString());
    }

    public Item()
    {}

    public Item(String theTitle)
    {
        title = theTitle;
    }

    public String getTitle()
    {
        return title;
    }
}

class CD extends Item
{
    private String artist;
    private String [] members;
    private int number;

    public CD(String theTitle, String theBand, int Snumber, String... keywords)
    {
        super(theTitle);
        this.artist = theBand;
        this.number = Snumber;
    }

    public void addband(String... member)
    {
        this.members = member;
    }

    public String getArtist()
    {
        return artist;
    }

    public String [] getMembers()
    {
        return members;   
    }

    public String toString()
    {
        return  "-Music-" + "\n" + "band: " + artist + "\n" + "# songs: " + number + "\n" + "members: " + members + "\n"  + "\n" + super.toString() + "\n";
    }

    public void print()
    {
        System.out.println(toString());
    }
}
```

I do have other information in the items class like a nook class, movie class that i didnt show. I would like to keep everything the way i have it set up..

So, if the other items are printing fine than maybe its the cast in the addbandmember function thats giving me problems?

Comment: Don't add newlines to toString() output.  This leads to a garbled mess when printing out List and Map or using a debugger.  The toString() output is not meant to be user display information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Arrays don't have a useful `toString()` implementation. You can print out the members in a loop or use the [Arrays.toString()](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString(java.lang.Object[])) method to do this for you:

```
return "-Music-" + "\n"
    + "band: " + artist + "\n"
    + "# songs: " + number + "\n"
    + "members: " + Arrays.toString(members) + "\n"
    + "\n"
    + super.toString() + "\n";
```

Answer (score 6):

`members` is printing the way it is since it's an array (you can tell this by the fact its output as **members: [Ljava.lang.String;**@61de33 ).

Instead you need to iterate through it and print each element.

e.g.

```
for (String member : members) {
   ...
}
```

The simplest way is to use Arrays.toString(). Alternatively append to a `StringBuilder` and then print to this. You can be cleverer, and use [StringUtils.join()](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html#join%28java.lang.Object[],%20char%29) from [Apache Commons Lang](http://commons.apache.org/lang), which will give you more control.

Comment: I was under the impression that StringBuilder was preferable to StringBuffer

Comment: @kgrad - to follow up, yes, it's preferred. Due to less synchronisation in the object.